# Windows Phone - ScheduledTaskAgent update the Live Tile Count

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, scheduled-tasks, live-tile

I have ScheduledTaskAgent and in this agent, when some condition is true, I want update the count in Live Tile. Something like this code:

```
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
if ( tile != null)
{
    StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
    data.Title = "Title text here";
    data.Count = 1;
    tile.Update(data);
}
```

but in the first line, I have this Exception:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method
>   'First' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

What I shloud do to solve this exception? I have to import some library or somehow connect the ScheduledTaskAgent with app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved: missing namespace

> System.Linq;